# How to get value from a js function

Tags: javascript, krpano

I'm using the **KRPano** plugin for street viewer. I've a `<hotspot>` that needs to show a tooltip with a value when I click on it. That value I need to take it from a JS function. So I added a `<style>` to my **hotspot**:

```
<style name="styletooltips"
    onclick="exhibit(); set(layer[text].html, get(js(getText()))); "           
/>
```

My `js` function:

```
function getText()
{
    return "Hello World!";
}
```

I tried it that way but I keep getting `null`. If I take out the `get`before the `js` it shows literally `js(getText())`.

P.D: the `exhibit()` is **KRPano** action that shows the layer with the tooltip.

Comment: @Renan thanks for creating the Tag. I couldn't

Comment: Just keep participating, you will be able to create tags once you reach 1,500 rep ;)

Comment: What is getText in this case? a JS method?

Comment: @DylanCorriveau Yes, I improve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used KRPano very much, nor do I have an enviroment to test atm, but I do believe the get isn't necessary. I believe you would just need to do:

```
<style name="styletooltips"
    onclick="exhibit(); set(layer[text].html, js(getText())); "           
/>
```

If you look in the KRPano [documentation](http://krpano.com/docu/actions/#get), it says the get will try to:

```
Resolve the 'variable' to its value.
```

In this case, there isn't a variable in use, just a method. You should be safe to just call js and use the return (since it is a string literal).

Edit: I just noticed the parameters list for get, and it makes complete sense for your instance.

```
variable (Any Variable):
When the variable doesn't exists, then get() will return null.
```

Edit 2: Another option would be to try setting a variable with the value, then passing that. Example:

```
<style name="styletooltips"
    onclick="exhibit(); var item = js(getText()); set(layer[text].html, item)); "           
/>
```

Comment: I actually tried that way before but it shows at the layer "js(getText())". Like it doesn't recognize the JS method.

Comment: It throws an error? or just does nothing when you try that? Also, are you using the flash player at all? There is a mention in the documentation about setting security restrictions when using js... http://krpano.com/docu/actions/#js

Comment: I doesn't show an error, it shows a string with "js(getText())" I mean exactly that.